# Pythonic Way to Sort a List of Comma Separated Numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

**Sample Input**

```
20, 71146620
100, 26867616
10, 02513583
10, 52811698
100, 23859051
```

I read it in from a file as a command line argument to a list with

```
lin = [i.strip() for i in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()]
```

that list looks like `['20, 71146620', '100, 26867616', '10, 02513583', '10, 52811698', '100, 23859051']`

My hope is to find the most pythonic way to sort this list, first for the first value and then for the second so that it looks like:

`['10, 02513583', '10, 52811698', '20, 71146620', '100, 23859051', '100, 26867616', ]`

I'm currently trying to convert it to a list of key value pairs, but I'm not sure that's the right direction to take.

Comment: Two things to remember - 1/ Standard Dictionaries only have 1 value per key so you would loose on 10: entry, 2/ Standard Dictionaries can not be "sorted".  So key, value pairs is the wrong name if your example data & output is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to parse the pairs into lists and then just sort them:

```
lin = [i.strip().split(', ') for i in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()]
lin = sorted(lin)
```

In case you want to sort numerically, just cast to numbers:

```
lin = [map(int, i.strip().split(', ')) for i in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()]
lin = sorted(lin)
```

Comment: Yes I was hoping for numerical sort. Thank you both. Wish I could select both as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the lines as strings, by using a key function

```
def two_ints(s):
    return map(int, s.split(","))

with open("num.txt") as f:
    for line in sorted(f, key=two_ints):
        print line
```

It really depends whether you want the result to be a list of strings, or a list of lists of ints.

Once you have converted to int, there is no way to recover the leading zero on "02513583", so leaving the result as strings may be preferable

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lin = sorted([[int(j) for j in i.split(",")] for i in f])
print lin
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the csv module and feed it to sort (with a string to integer conversion)

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    result = sorted(list(map(int,row)) for row in cr)
```

outcome:

```
>>> result
[[10, 2513583],
 [10, 52811698],
 [20, 71146620],
 [100, 23859051],
 [100, 26867616]]
```

`sort` does exactly what's asked here: it uses natural sorting order of lists